Virtual Environment Directory
I try to run python setup.py develop on my virtual environment. I go to the directory that contains the file and try to develop setup.py files. But it shows an error that I am still on where the python.exe directory is.

(venv_preprocessing) PS D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\venv_preprocessing\simple_pipeline> python setup.py develop

No Python at '"C:\Program Files\Python311\python.exe'

How to solve this?

It looks like you created a virtual environment with Python 3.11 that was installed for all users in the Program Files directory. That version of Python may have been uninstalled since, breaking the virtual environment. Either reinstall Python 3.11 to that location, or recreate the virtual environment with the currently installed version of Python.

Ah, you're right. Thank you for your help sir.
